# How to connect html table with excel spreadsheet using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, excel

I am creating a system with a table with name, attendance status, date, time in and out as columns. How could I connect it to excel spreadsheet which acts as data base using php

I tried watching videos from youtube but they're from 5 or more years ago which made me wonder if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: How can we comment on a 'better way' if we haven't seen what way to compare to? Please show what you have tried see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example However, in general SO is not the place to get comments on whether code is optimal or the 'best' libraries. But have you tried reading from a CSV file? This may be good enough for your purposes and saves worrying about versions of xls etc.

Answer (score 0):

Natively, PHP Does not support Excel File. However you can use the [PHP Spreadsheet Library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) to open and read Excel Files.

To download PHPSpreadsheet:

1. Download and install a package manager called Composer.
2. Open the command prompt (or terminal), and navigate to your project folder cd Project_Folder
3. Run composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet

Use the following code to read excel and show it in a table.

```
<table><?php
// (A) PHPSPREADSHEET TO LOAD EXCEL FILE
require "vendor/autoload.php";
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load("2-demo.xlsx");
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
 
// (B) LOOP THROUGH ROWS OF CURRENT WORKSHEET
foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
  // (B1) READ CELLS
  $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
  $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
 
  // (B2) OUTPUT HTML
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) { echo "<td>". $cell->getValue() ."</td>"; }
  echo "</tr>";
}
?></table>
```